# What is django? Can i use it with jsf?

Tags: django, jsf

Hello at present I am using jsf+hibernate+spring and i need to get data from session using django and iam new to it so any one can help me....

Comment: What sort of a question is this?

Answer (score -1):

Django is a python web framework.  JSF, Hibernate and Spring are Java technologies.  You can't use them together (theoretically you could do some Jython magic, but not recommended).

Comment: Not recommended? Django is perfectly compatible with Jython.

Comment: But you wouldn't use Hibernate/JSF, would you?

Comment: Why wouldn't you? You'll have to be more careful concerning the common part (database) to avoid data overrides from both systems. But you can perfectly use those technologies together. This is sometimes done in migration projects.

Comment: Perhaps it was a bad answer to a bad question.  The original title asked if you could use jsf with django.  Sure you could probably make it work but it seems like a whole heap of pain.